# What're the major difference between SafeBuffer and SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Where are the major differences? I know that SafeBuffer derives SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid but what else?

When should I use one versus the other?

I need to allocate and control a native array (either on CPU or GPU). Should my managed custom array implement SafeBuffer or SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid? SafeBuffer as a name sounds more reasonable, but why should I implement it and have to call Initialize before using it?

Answer (score 3):

> Where are the major differences?

Everywhere, they have nothing in common.  SaveBuffer inherits from SafeHandle to take advantage of the critical finalizer that SafeHandle provides.  Which enures the buffer is released even in the most dire circumstances, like a hard crash in the program that would normally prevent the finalizer from executing.

SaveBuffer is a wrapper for unmanaged memory that was obtained by an operating system call.  It has exactly *one* method that's still abstract, the ReleaseHandle() method.  Since different winapi calls have different ways to release the handle that's associated with the memory.  For example, LocalAlloc() requires LocalFree().  SysAllocString() requires SysFreeString().  MapViewOfFile() requires UnmapViewOfFile(), etcetera.

You can derive your own class from SaveBuffer() to take advantage of the safe handle guarantees.  It needs a constructor that take the unmanaged pointer and call SetHandle().  And it needs to implement ReleaseHandle() to release the memory again.

Whether you should actually do this is **very** questionable.  The ReleaseHandle() method is called by a critical finalizer.  There are a large number of things you cannot do in such a method, requirements on critical finalizers are steep to ensure that the finalizer itself does cause any corruption that would prevent other critical finalizers from running.  The CLR runs in a mode that prevents exceptions from being generated for example.  It only really matters in custom CLR hosting environments that give strong guarantees for up-time, SQL Server is the primary example.  It's okay to use it if you make an operating system call, that is code that's solid as a rock.  A GPU buffer, meh, not so much.  You are likely to be ahead by just creating your own wrapper with its own finalizer.  You'll have a *much* easier time debugging mishaps when the release call fails.

Comment: I still don't understand. SafeBuffer inherits from SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid, including the abstract ReleaseHandle(). What you have said applies to SafeHandle too, right?

What I don't understand is the extra stuffs that SafeBuffer has and why we need to call Initialize before using a SafeBuffer instance (while it's not necessary when using a SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid instance).

To control a native array, I can just use SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid where handle = IntPtr(malloc(...)), right?